# developing a new package and getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a little application where I wanted to create a module containg a small group of classes, but when I try to import the classes from the main application, I get the error:

```
 my_project python3 main.py 
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import receivers
  File "/home/mario/Documents/python/my_project/receivers/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from icinga import Icinga
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icinga'
```

The file in the project are:

```
├── main.py
└── receivers
    ├── icinga.py
    ├── __init__.py
```

where `main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import receivers

icinga = receivers.icinga.Icinga()
```

the file `receivers/icinga.py`

```
class Icinga:

    def __init__(self):
        print("I'm Icinga!")
```

the file `receivers/__init__.py`

```
print('1')
from icinga import Icinga
print('2')
```

Can someone please tell me what I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. maybe try add a dot `.` before the module name to indicate it is a relative directory import `from .icinga import Icinga`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to import the Icinga class, you can do it as

```
from receivers.icinga import Icinga
```

If you want to call the import statement on receivers, you should alter the **init**.py, on 2nd line, to:

```
from .icinga import Icinga
```

I reproduced your problem here, and was able to solve it like that.

Edit:

Doing this second thing (on __init__.py), you would be able to call it on the main.py as:

```
import receivers
receivers.icinga.Icinga()
```

Comment: The first import works, thanks!

May I just ask you how I should call the second import from the main?

Comment: You don't call the second import from the main. The second one needs to be in the ```__init__.py``` file, if you just want to import it.